How to Implement Progressive Cell Coloring in a General Mesh or Tiling?
Here are some examples of what I am talking about using Voronoi for simplicity:
Given:

That can be colored depending on which cell is randomly chosen:

I feel like there would be a better name for this concept, but I don't know it.
This code can highlight a random Voronoi cell:
Graphics[
{GraphicsComplex[
   MeshCoordinates[vor], {Thick, Blue, MeshCells[vor, 1],  MeshCells[vor, 0], Opacity[0.2], White, 
    MeshCells[vor, 2]}
    ],
    Black, RandomChoice[MeshPrimitives[vor, 2]]
    }
  ]

and you can highlight the adjacent cells to it using (did for a different voronoi):
vor=VoronoiMesh[data];
fromLabel[vm_, labels_] := Ordering[Length /@ vm["Faces"]][[labels]]
toLabel[vm_, indices_] := ReplaceAll[
    indices,
    Thread[Ordering[Length /@ vm["Faces"]]->Range[Length[vm["Faces"]]]]
]

highlightAdjacentFaces[vm_, label_] := HighlightMesh[
    vm,
    Thread[{2, toLabel[vm, vm["FaceFaceConnectivity"][[fromLabel[vm, label]]]]}]
]

vm = vor;
highlightAdjacentFaces[vm, Length[data]]

Which gives:

While a natural thought is to look at the adjacency matrix of the cells, then test each component to see if it shares a vertex or edge with the region before it, this seems like a very procedural approach and it is not very Mathematica-like.
I am not just interested in convex or Voronoi tilings. For example, this lemon tiling is also interesting:

which I highlighted the rasterized version using this code and Paint:
rowLineQuantity=RandomInteger[{2,10}];
oddColQuantity=RandomInteger[{1,10}];
Plot[
Table[
Sin[x+FractionBox["1", "2"] (-1-SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"-", "1"}], ")"}], "i"])*Pi]-2 i,{i,1,rowLineQuantity}],{x,-Pi/2,FractionBox["1", "2"] (-1+4 *oddColQuantity) \[Pi]},
AspectRatio->Automatic,Axes->False,PlotStyle->Blue]


MeshConnectivityGraph and GraphDistance  might come in handy.

As suggested by @flinty, use MeshConnectivityGraph and GraphDistance.
colorByDistance[mesh_, start_, cf_ : ColorData["CoffeeTones"]] := 
 Module[{polygons, graph, distances},
  polygons = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2];
  graph = MeshConnectivityGraph[mesh, 2];
  distances = GraphDistance[graph, VertexList[graph][[start]]];

  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], 
    MapThread[{cf[#2/Max[distances]], #1} &, {polygons, distances}]}]
  ]

SeedRandom[100];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}]];
colorByDistance[mesh, 70]


